# GRPC C# - Where are the well known grpc types stored to reference them? Unable to import google.protobuf.Timestamp

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, grpc

I have a very simple protobuf file as below

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GrpcService1.Protos";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";
import "Protos/ReportingStatus.proto";

package GrpcService1;

service MetricReportingService {
    rpc ReportMetricData(MetricMessage) returns (StatusMessage);
}
message MetricMessage {
    int32 id = 1;
    int32 value = 2;
    google.protobuf.Timestamp last_updated = 3;
}

message StatusMessage {
    ReportingStatus status = 1;
}
```

When I build the solution I get the below error

```
1>Protos/MetricProducer.proto(16,9): error : "google.protobuf.TimeStamp" is not defined.
```

I am using Visual Studio 2019 Ver 16.10.0. I have added the Grpc.aspnetcore meta package. I have tried to see if the well known proto files are installed elsewhere but am not sure how the well known proto types are referenced. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Protobuf timestamp not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56031098/protobuf-timestamp-not-found)

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately the responses to the linked question does not help with Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds strange but restarting Visual Studio and rebuilding did the trick. Maybe I should have walked away and taken a break earlier. :-)

Comment: How did you resolve this? I still have the same problem with Grpc.ASpnetcore 2.43.0. Restart didn't help.

Answer (score 3):

Change

google.protobuf.TimeStamp last_updated = 3;

to

google.protobuf.Timestamp last_updated = 3;

Comment: Thanks. Updated it for case but still does not work. I have updated the question to reflect the same.

Comment: This could help me.